# Mnesia, select and secondary indexes

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I created indexes for table and have a question. Does mnesia:select use secondary indexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/tablesDatabases.html

> There are exceptions when the complete table is not scanned, for instance if part of the key is bound when searching an ordered_set table, or if it is a Mnesia table and there is a secondary index on the field that is selected/matched.